# OpenID associated with a wrong account

Tags: support

I am using my friends computer and I was trying to make a new account for stackexchange, but I must have done something wrong because now my email/ID is linked to my friend's account, and it didn't make a new account for me. Can anyone assist/advice ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Yes, dealing with 2 accounts on one computer is pretty tricky and requires constant use of log-out. The good idea here is to use browser's "porn mode" (Incognito/Private/InPrivate depending on browser) --- this way you can remain logged in normal mode while your friend can simultaneously operate in the incognito one.

Going back to your problem, this is something you can fix on your own; just use "my logins" tab in the profile page to remove your OpenID from the friend's account so you can use it to create a new account for you. [Here is an official support page about this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/edit-logins).

Comment: Yes, mbq is completely correct -- you'll need to remove that log-in credential from your friend's account, then open up a different browser (or an "incognito" browser) and log in that way. As you saw, when you try to log in when someone else is already logged in, you'll end up sharing an account!